# How do I return a random value from array based on filtered data?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to create a code that, when a button is pressed, a random value from my array is returned. More specifically, I have already created a code where upon button press, a random link from the array is returned, and the code presents the image. I want to take it a step further and have it so that the array can be filtered by criteria. I have the following array format in js: `{site: "(link here, and does not have parenthesis in the actual code)", series: "1", type: "SP", dice: "1", rps: "S", species: "N/A", name: "Isabelle"}` with 400+ more lines of the array formatted the same. My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Card Selector</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainimgbg.css">
</head>
<body class="light-theme">
    <h1>amiibo Selector</h1>
    <p id="msg">To Do:</p>
    <ul>
      <li class="list">Add exclusion parameters</li>
      <li class="list">Add sanrio images</li>
    </ul>
    <input type=button id="btnSearch" value="Select" onclick="GetValue();" />
<div id="message"></div>
    <script src="gendetailedextra.js"></script>
    <script>alert("This site is a work in progress.")</script>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to view the full site.</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

My js:

```
'use strict'
var myarray= new Array(
    {400 line array formatted as mentioned above},);
function GetValue()
{

    var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
    //alert(random);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML='<img src='+random+'>';
}
```

I was looking at the code of a name generator, and found an HTML code snippet that seemed useful, but I don't know how to implement it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function click_usage(box) {
    if ($(box).is(':checked')) {
        if ($(box).attr('id')=='all') {
            $('.usage-cb').prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $('#all').prop('checked', false);
        }
    }
}
//-->
</script>
```

I figure the best way to do this would be some sort of checkboxes, which I can probably google how to format on the HTML end. Additionally, I have run into the issue that because I now have multiple pieces of data in the array other than the links, the code no longer provides me with the image embedded. I am willing to sacrifice this feature if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is all fine, except for one tiny detail.

When you call `GetValue()`, you get a random element of your array. This element, however, is not a string with the URL, but an object (`{site:"abc", rps: "S", ...}`). To access values inside an object, you use a `.` separator. Therefore, the line in your function should look like this:

```js
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML='<img src=' + random.site + '>';
```

(`random.site` instead of `random`. If you need a different property, use `random.property_name_here`)

As of the code you found from the other website:
This code requires jQuery and is specific to the HTML of that site. All this code does is uncheck certain checkboxes under certain conditions.

For better readability, I would format your code this way:

```js
let myArray= [{site:"abc", type:"SP", ...}, {...}, {...}, {...}];
function randomFromArray(arr) {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=`<img src="${randomFromArray(myArray).site}">`;
```

Edit:
Function to filter your array by criteria.

```js
function filterArr(array, field, value) {
  return array.filter(function (k) {
    return k[field] === value;
  });
}
//usage:
filterArr(myArray, "rps", "S"); //returns all elements with `rps: "S"`
filterArr(myArray, "type", "SP"); //returns all elements with `type: "SP"`
```

So to get a random element from a filtered array:

```
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=`<img src="${randomFromArray(filterArr(myArray, "type", "SP")).site}">`;
```

To make your button use the new functions: (remove `onclick="GetValue();"`)

```
document.getElementById("btnSearch").addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=`<img src="${randomFromArray(filterArr(myArray, "type", "SP")).site}">`;
}
```

Learn more: [Object (MDN docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) [`return` keyword (MDN docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) [Template literals (MDN docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: This fixed my image problem, but changing the code seems to have broken the button. Additionally, I'm still trying to figure out how to implement the filters. Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: Yes, you would need to change your button if you want to use my modified function. Didn't at first understand what you tried to filter, but I think I get it now, and will edit my asnwer.